# Show hidden icons button out of place

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, notification-area

I recently got a Yoga 2 Pro (3200x1800) resolution and it's mostly been great except for one aggravating but minor issue: the "show hidden icons" button on the taskbar isn't vertically centered and has way too much padding. Furthermore, the issue gets worse with Windows 8.1 Update 1.

[image: Image taken from Ars Technica's Yoga 2 Pro review. It shows what the button looks like in Windows 8.1]
[image: Image taken from my current laptop, running Windows 8.1 Update 1]
The first image is taken from Ars Technica's Yoga 2 Pro review.  It shows what the button looks like in Windows 8.1.
The second image is taken from my current laptop, running Windows 8.1 Update 1.

There is way too much space on either side of the button, and it is not centered vertically.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

(yes, this is a duplicate of http://www.reddit.com/r/windows8/comments/2a74rp/show_hidden_icons_button_out_of_place/ after I was unable to find a solution there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which update, but a recent Windows update has fixed my issue.  Install all recommended/important/optional updates to fix it.  It's now nice and centered :D

Comment: Huh. I just went through every installed update and also [the entire list](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3028013) of non-security updates from 2014. Nothing seems to indicate a fix for relevant scaling/DPI/icon/taskbar issues. It must have snuck in along with something else.

Answer (score 2):

The default scaling changed to 250% with the Update (with 8.1 the maximum scaling available was 200%) so setting this back to 200% fixes this. The standard DPI for a monitor is 96 DPI, and the 250% scaling is closer to this than 200% is the reason for the change in scaling.

Comment: For me, it's very off center when it's at 250%, slightly off center when it's at 200% (look closely, it is definitely off center), and perfect at 150%. The first image from the Arstechnica review is at 200% scaling, and it's still off center.  The second is at 250% scaling.

Can you explain what you mean by the 250% scaling is closer to this than 200%?

Comment: This problem should not, in an ideal world, be dependent on dpi scaling though.